# Use xhr.overrideMimeType but get server response first?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I want to get a Base64 encoded file from the server in order to use it in a dataURL so I use:

```
xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
```

So I get the unprocessed data to perform the base64 encoding on.

But I also want to get the mimetype originally returned from the server to declare my dataURL:
`var dataUrl = 'data:'+mimetype+';base64,'+b64;`

when I try something like the following:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, false);
var mimetype = xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type');
xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
xhr.send(null);
```

the content-type returned is always null

Full source:

```
function getFileDataUrl(link,mimetype)
{
  var url = location.origin+link;
  var getBinary = function (url) 
  {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, false);
    if(mimetype == null)
    {
        mimetype = xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type');
        console.log('mimetype='+mimetype);
    }
    xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
    xhr.send(null);
    return xhr.responseText;
   };
   var bin = getBinary(url);
   var b64 = base64Encode(bin);
   var dataUrl = 'data:'+mimetype+';base64,'+b64;
   return dataUrl;
}
var dataUrl = getFileDataUrl(link,null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `responseType` of `XMLHttpRequest` to `"blob"` or `"arraybuffer"` then use `FileReader`, `FileReader.prototype.readAsDataURL()` on `response`. Though note, `onload` event of `FileReader` returns results asynchronously. To read file synchronously you can use `Worker` and `FileReaderSync()`

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
  // do stuff with `reader.result`
  console.log(reader.result);
}
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function() {
  reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
}
xhr.send(null);
```

---

At chromium synchronous `XMLHttpRequest()` is deprecated, see https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

You can use `Promise` at main thread to get `data URI` of requested resource using either `Worker` or when `FileReader` `load` event is dispatched. Or use synchronous `XMLHttpRequest()` and `FileReaderSync()` at `Worker` thread, then listen for `message` event at main thread, use `.then()` to get `Promise` value.

Main thread

```
var worker = new Worker("worker.js");
var url = "path/to/resource";

function getFileDataUrl(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {        
    worker.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
      resolve(e.data)
    });
    worker.postMessage(url);
  })
}

getFileDataUrl(url)
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err)
});
```

worker.js

```
var reader = new FileReaderSync();
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

self.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
  var reader = new FileReaderSync();
  request.open("GET", e.data, false);
  request.responseType = "blob";
  request.send(null);
  self.postMessage(reader.readAsDataURL(request.response));
});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/gayWpkTVydmKYMnPr3jD?p=preview

Comment: i can't set responseType when using XMLHttpRequest synchronously for some reason. do you have an example for the use of Woker and FileReaderSync()?

Comment: @subject42 Why do you need to use `XMLHttpRequest` synchronously?

Comment: I needed to use it synchronously because further execution depended on its results, also further user interaction should be avoided during loading process of the file.